# Parallel overlays in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have 2 `columns` of `blocks` side by side in 1 slide:

```
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{left block 1}
      left block 1
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{left block 2}
      left block 2
    \end{block}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{right block 1}
      right block 1
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{right block 2}
      right block 2
    \end{block}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

What I would like to realize is: `left block 1` and `right block 1` are shown initially, when I left-click the mouse, `left block 2` and `right block 2` are shown **at the same time** under them.

I don't know if it is possible to do it by `onslide` or `pause`... Could anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add overlay specifications to the lower blocks, as in:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{left block 1}
      left block 1
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}<2>{left block 2}
      left block 2
    \end{block}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{right block 1}
      right block 1
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}<2>{right block 2}
      right block 2
    \end{block}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you... What if the "lower blocks" are not "block"? I mean, sometimes I just want to show two sentences `left sentence 2` and `right sentence 2`, it seems that `<2>left sentence 2` or `<2>right sentence 2` does not work...

Comment: The command `\only` is overlay-specification aware, for example, `\only<2>{left sentence 2}` etc. Note that if you want different portions of text to appear on different slides, you need to modify the overlay specifications accordingly. E.g. you might use `<2->` to mean the overlay should start on slide 2 and remain, or `<3>` to mean shown only on slide 3.